# How to show cursor focus (vertical-line) in the input

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an input of type number, I should format the entered value to a specific format which returns a string, so as a solution I added a second input of type string and hide the input[type=number] but the user sees only the input[type=string] but enter the value in the first one (number type)

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="price" (ngModelChange)="formatPrice()" class="hide-number-input" required>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="priceValue" class="show-text-input">
```

so in my function `formatPrice()` I set the formatted price to `priceValue`. In my css file, I declared:

```
.hide-number-input {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

.show-text-input {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative
}
```

It works fine but the problem is my cursor is not shown, so no focus on my `input[type=string]`, no vertical line shown in the input although I can write

The idea is to hide the input of type number, should not be seen, so I know that my cursor is in the hidden input, that's fine but I have to show it also in the input of type string

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `position:absolute;` to visible the vertical cursor

```
.hide-number-input {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.show-text-input {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

Hope this will be helpful for you

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i don't want show the input of type number, without position: absolute; it will not but hidden

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this for **auto focus**

```
<input id="name" type="text" #myInput />
{{ myInput.focus() }}
```

Check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dglats

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:
Try setting .hide-number-input's z-index to 1 or less. This will allow the user to select the visible input.

```
.hide-number-input {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    }

    .show-text-input {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    }
```

Explanation: 
In the class .hide-number-input you have set the z-index to 2. In the .show-text-input class you have set z-index to 1. This means, that even though the input with the class .hide-number-input has an opacity is 0 (and can't be seen), it's z index is higher than .show-text-input (z-index 1). So the input with the class .show-text-input can not be selected. It has been positioned behind the 'hidden' one.

When you attempt to click on the visible input field, you are actually clicking on the hidden one, and the hidden one is has the focus (vertical-line), but as the input field is hidden you can't see this.

Comment: yes that's what actually I want, input field is hidden correctly, but i want to show the focus on the shown input in the same time when the focus is in the hidden input